# sklearn PLSRegression - Variance of X explained by latent vectors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, variance

I performed a partial least squares regression using Python's [sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression)

Is there a way to retrieve the fraction of explained variance for X, i.e. **R<sup>2</sup>(X)**, for each PLS component? I'm looking for something similar to the explvar() function from the R pls package. However, I'd also appreciate any suggestions on how to compute it myself.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25266514/1276810) and there is one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706516/1276810) that explains how to get the variance of Y. I guess, that "variance in Y" is what was asked for in that case. That's why I opened a new question - hope that's O.K.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to find a solution for the problem. The following gives the fraction of variance in X explained by each latent vector after PLS regression:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import cross_decomposition

# X is a numpy ndarray with samples in rows and predictor variables in columns
# y is one-dimensional ndarray containing the response variable

total_variance_in_x = np.var(X, axis = 0)

pls1 = cross_decomposition.PLSRegression(n_components = 5)
pls1.fit(X, y) 

# variance in transformed X data for each latent vector:
variance_in_x = np.var(pls1.x_scores_, axis = 0) 

# normalize variance by total variance:
fractions_of_explained_variance = variance_in_x / total_variance_in_x
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for this solution. When X is multivariate, you would have to do sum("total_variance_in_x"). Also, if you calculate (1 - "fractions_of_explained_variance"), you should get an array with the cumulative explained variance.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about this, so if someone can contribute something ...

following these among others:

https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-12-11-pca-explained-variance

https://www.ibm.com/docs/de/spss-statistics/24.0.0?topic=reduction-total-variance-explained

```
variance_in_x = np.var(pls1.x_scores_, axis = 0) 
fractions_of_explained_variance = variance_in_x / np.sum(variance_in_x)
```